# Is it a good idea to charge multiple Li-Ion batteries using a single buck converter?

Tags: buck, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller, mppt, bms

I am trying to implement a DIY MPPT into my solar tracker project and I wanted to know if it was possible to charge all of the three li-ion 3.7v batteries in series with just one feedback buck converter; BMS modules charge each cell individually so they can discharge every cell that has stored extra charges, which makes sense to me, but what makes the batteries charge unevenly in the first place?

Comment: Manufacturing tolerances between cells, slight temperature diffirences betweel cells, etc... Factors like that cause the imbalances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most BMS modules do actually charge all cells in series with a single converter. They just have extra circuitry to discharge single cells that are charged too much. This can be achieved by simply putting a resistor in parallel with each cell which can be activated using a FET to discharge the cell a bit. If you want a fancy solution, you can also recycle the charge drained from one cell to charge the others.

There are also BMS modules that only balance the cells and don't include charging circuitry. This might be a good choice if you want to build your own charger but don't want to worry about balancing the cells yourself.

The reason why the cells have different voltages is that their capacities are not the same, one cell might be full with 2000mAh while another one might need 2200mAh. Their voltages therefore have to be equalized somehow. They may also dissipate more or less of the charging energy as heat, depending on how efficient they are (as was already commented on the question). The cells will also have different self-discharge rates.

Answer (score 0):

When the equivalent capacitance of batteries are mismatched, the weaker cells charge and discharge faster. This quality factor is never given by suppliers and changes with stress by heat and extended under/over charge.

You know about  tolerances in ecaps being 10% or more, the same is true with good quality Lithium cells.

The last 10% or less of battery capacity is done during the CV mode as current declines to say 5% of CC. This weaker  current is what BMS must be capable of bypassing so the weaker cell accepts no further charge.

So a 2A charger needs a 2A BMS , but if used conservatively, you might get away with less bypass power. 4.2V x 2A is 8.4W of bypass heat absorbed.

With abuse to batteries , BMS use is critical to avoid the dead pack after 50 cycle common from the weak link. Using a series BMS will improve your changes of getting 500 cycles in consumer grade cells.